# Rails weird bug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I tried to open a page which is not in public folder then it automatically creates that file and saves, why?

```
For Eg.
If I hit http://localhost:3000/a5his.html   
then it creates a5his.html in public folder.
```

Isn't there a way to avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you have something like "caches_page" in your controller?

You should show us some more code, especially controller. I am almost sure that such behaviour is not the rails' default way of life.

Comment: True, `caches_page` + wrongly defined `catch_all` route = disaster.